# Dropzone.js callback access Angular scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropzone.js

I've built a simple AngularJS directive to implement Dropzone.js on elements.
I'd like to display uploaded files using an ng-repeat outside of the directive, but I can't make it work since the 'addedfile' callback of the element seems to be creating a copy of the array (scope.files). The callback can read the array (or the copy of the array) but when I push a new element on it doesn't affect the ng-repeat. How can I make it work ?

```
.directive('dropzone', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {

            el.dropzone({
                url: attrs.url,
                maxFilesize: attrs.maxsize,
                init: function() {
                    scope.files.push({file: 'added'}); // here works
                    this.on('success', function(file, json) {
                    });
                    this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
                        scope.files.push({file: 'added'}); // here doesn't work
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this happends outside the realm of Angular you have to notify Angular of the change by wrapping it in an $apply:

```
this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
  scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.files.push({file: 'added'});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need drop files functionality in angular you can use this lightweight directive:
[angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
  <div class="drop-box" ng-file-drop="onFileSelect($files);">drop files here</div>
```

JS:

```
//inject angular file upload directive.
angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var $file = $files[i];
      $upload.upload({
        url: 'my/upload/url',
        file: $file,
        progress: function(e){}
      }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
      }); 
    }
  }
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

function dropZone() {

```
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    //scope.files="esto contiene files";
    console.log(scope);


    element.dropzone({
        url: "upload.php",
        maxFilesize: 100,
        paramName: "uploadfile",
        maxThumbnailFilesize: 5,
        init: function () {
            scope.files.push({file: 'added'});
            this.on('success', function (file, json) {
            });
            this.on('addedfile', function (file) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    alert(file);
                    scope.files.push({file: 'added'});
                });
            });
            this.on('drop', function (file) {
                alert('file');
            });
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: angular.js:14525 TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Dropzone.init (directives.js:377)     I did what appeared above. what is the problem? Thank you

Comment: Please edit your original question to include the question that you added in a comment.